# Can a specialist in a healthcare facility refuse to accept a previously discharged patient? (Tenn.)

Tags: united-states, health

Consider a person had been to a specialist practice facility (say facility A) for a medical concern. Unhappy with the specific doctor, he/she decides to leave the facility and look for a new facility (facility B) and hence the facility A discharges the patient. Can the facility A then refuse service for the patient in a future date and time because they have been previously released from practice. I'm interested on the legality of this action in United States and in particular Tennessee

Answer (score 1):

Can a specialist in a healthcare facility refuse to accept a patient?

Yes, if in stable condition. Which doesn't mean as much as you'd like.